# How to generate a QR to an android app that I uploaded into google play

Tags: android, google-play, qr-code

I have uploaded android app into google play and I want to generate QR code for it.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Copy the playstore-url of your application

   e.g.: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.springpad
2. Open a QR-Generator ( there many on the web )

   e.g.: http://goqr.me/
3. Enter your apps playstore-url and generate the code with 1 more click!

Comment: Android supports a URI format like:

`market://details?id=org.example.foo`

See https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/BarcodeContents

However I think that linking to `https://play.google.com/` is slightly better as it also opens the Play app on Android, but, will also show something reasonable on other platforms.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this handy tool: [QR-Code-Generator](http://www.qr-code-generator.com/)